# Error al intentar crear un combobox con objetos en Java

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8, combobox, model

Estoy tratando de crear un combobox que me permita guardar dos o más valores en cada item del combo. Algo asi como los elementos select en html donde puedes puedes guardar en el atributo value de un  un ID por ejemplo y mostrar un texto entre las etiquetas, que esta relacionado con ese ID. Algo asi intento hacer en los combobox en Java. A modo de prueba he creado una clase llamada Categorias, al cual colocare a continuación:

```
 package mainDashboard;
/*
*/
 public class Categorias {

    private int id;
private String nombre;
private int tipo_articulo;

    public Categorias(){
    }


    public Categorias(int id, String nombre, int tipo_articulo){
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo_articulo = tipo_articulo;
}


    //GETTERS Y SETTERS PARA ESTA CLASE

    public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

    public int getTipo_Articulo() {
    return tipo_articulo;
}

public void setTipo_Articulo(int tipo_articulo) {
    this.tipo_articulo = tipo_articulo;
}


   @Override
public String toString() {
    return this.id+", "+this.nombre+", "+this.tipo_articulo;
}


}
```

En esta clase se encuentran los atributos y metodos para las Categorias.

y en un JFrame pruebo crear un model para el Combobox y llenarlo con objetos Categorias.

codigo:

```
 package mainDashboard;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class ConfArticuloView extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public ConfArticuloView() {

    initComponents();

    //se construye la tabla para los tipos de articulos        
    CrearModeloTipoArticulo();         
    CrearModeloTablaCategorias();

    //Mostrar los tipos de Articulos
    CargarTablaTiposArticulos();

    //crear el model para combobox
    DefaultComboBoxModel value = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    jComboBox2prueba.removeAllItems();
    jComboBox2prueba.setModel(value);

    //agregar información al combo
    value.addElement(new Categorias(1, "Zapato", 1));
    value.addElement(new Categorias(2, "Cartera", 2));
    value.addElement(new Categorias(3, "Celular", 3));      
 }

  //evento de cambio para el combobox
      private void jComboBox2pruebaItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                  

    Categorias cat = (Categorias)jComboBox2prueba.getSelectedItem();
    int codigo_art = cat.getTipo_Articulo();
    String nombre = cat.getNombre();

    System.out.print(nombre + " - " + codigo_art);
}

}
```

Sucede que, si no agrego el evento ItemStateChanged al combo y mando a correr el Jframe para probar, el combo aparece lleno de información pero se muestra de esta forma:

[image: Combobox Imagen]

aparecen todos todos los datos separados por coma, lo cual no luce muy bien, deberia solo aparecer la Descripción, porque los demás datos (los IDs) se necesitan ocultos.

Ahora bien, si agrego el evento ItemStateChanged al combo para detectar cuando se seleccionen items diferentes, y mando a correr el Jframe, me aparece este error y el Jframe nunca aparece en pantalla:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at mainDashboard.ConfArticuloView.jComboBox2pruebaItemStateChanged(ConfArticuloView.java:2184)
at mainDashboard.ConfArticuloView.access$3100(ConfArticuloView.java:20)
at mainDashboard.ConfArticuloView$32.itemStateChanged(ConfArticuloView.java:1272)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1223)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1271)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1330)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.intervalRemoved(JComboBox.java:1352)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireIntervalRemoved(AbstractListModel.java:179)
at javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel.removeAllElements(DefaultComboBoxModel.java:174)
at javax.swing.JComboBox.removeAllItems(JComboBox.java:771)
at mainDashboard.ConfArticuloView.<init>(ConfArticuloView.java:45)
at mainDashboard.ConfArticuloView$39.run(ConfArticuloView.java:2222)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Yo soy un poco nuevo en este lenguaje y lo que intento es aprender a Llenar un Combobox con diferentes datos, para poder usarlo luego en un ejercicio más complejo que incluya extracción de data desde base de datos y cargar esta en un combo que estará incluido en algún formulario, ya que necesitare muchas veces los id de una tabla para guardarlos en otras tablas pero no le quiero mostrar al usuario un combo lleno de id si no los nombres o títulos vinculados a dichos ID (por ejemplo: tener un combo de ciudades en un formulario de contacto, donde cada ciudad tiene un ID, le mostrare al usuario los nombres de las ciudades en el combo pero en la base de datos solo guardaría el id de la ciudad seleccionada.)

Alguna sugerencia para solucionar los errores?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está en qué le estás entregando al ComboBox.
Creo que deberías crear las categorías de esta manera:

```
List<Categorias> categorias = new ArrayList<>();
Categorias cat1 = new Categorias(1, "Zapato", 1);
categorias.add(cat1);
Categorias cat2 = new Categorias(2, "Cartera", 2);
categorias.add(cat2);
Categorias cat3 = new Categorias(3, "Celular", 3);
categorias.add(cat3);
```

En el caso de pedirlas directamente a la base de datos mediante algún método del tipo: (este ejemplo es para Hibernate)

```
public List listarCategorias(){
    List <Categorias>categorias;
    SessionFactory sesionFact = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session sesion;
    sesion = sesionFact.openSession();
    sesion.beginTransaction();
    String consulta = "FROM Categorias";
    Query query = sesion.createQuery(consulta);
    categorias = query.list();
    sesion.getTransaction().commit();
    return categorias;
}
```

Si viene de la base de datos con un método similar la lista la llenaríamos de esta forma:

```
ClaseDondeImplementasteElCodigo claseDondeImplementasteElCodigo = new ClaseDondeImplementasteElCodigo();
List<Categorias> categorias = claseDondeImplementasteElCodigo.listarCategorias();
```

Después para el ComboBox si sólo quieres que te muestre el nombre:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel cbm =  new  DefaultComboBoxModel ();
cbm.addElement ( " --Seleccionar Categorías -- " );
for(Categorias c : categorias){ 
//Hace referencia a la lista de tipo Categorias
    cbm.addElement (c.getNombre());
}   
jComboBox2prueba.setModel(cbm) ;
```

Para el evento. si quieres recuperar un dato del ComboBox donde tienes solo un nombre, puedes implementar otro método que te busque por nombre:

```
public Categorias buscarCategoriasPorNombre(String categoriaBusqueda){
    Categorias categoria = new Categorias();

    SessionFactory sesionFact =  NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session sesion;
    sesion = sesionFact.openSession();
    sesion.beginTransaction();
    String consulta = "FROM Categorias c WHERE c.nombre LIKE '%"+categoriaBusqueda+"%'";
    Query query  = sesion.createQuery(consulta);
    List<Categorias> listaResultados = query.list();
    categoria.setId(listaResultados.get(0).getId());
    categoria.setNombre(listaResultados.get(0).getNombre());
    categoria.setTipo_Articulo(listaResultados.get(0).getTipo_Articulo());

    sesion.getTransaction().commit();

    return categoria;
}
```

Y después en el evento:

```
private void jComboBox2pruebaItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                  
   String nombreCat = (String)jComboBox2prueba.getSelectedItem();
   ClaseDondeImplementasteElCodigo claseDondeImplementasteElCodigo = new ClaseDondeImplementasteElCodigo();
   Categorias cat = claseDondeImplementasteElCodigo.buscarCategoriasPorNombre(nombreCat);
   int codigo_art = cat.getTipo_Articulo();
   String nombre = cat.getNombre();

   System.out.print(nombre + " - " + codigo_art);
}
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.